# Does a single _type with sparse fields have the same effect on the index as multiple types (in ElasticSearch)?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

How much do sparse fields apply when an index has only one type?  I'm in the position of making an index with a large number of small-ish documents all of the same type, and with a number of fields.  Only a fraction of the fields are populated thought all of the documents are of the same type.  According to this post there are concerns when the postings are sparse.  This seems to suggest though it might only be a problem if the index has **many** types.  What if the index only has one type?

> Fields that exist in one type will also consume resources for
>   documents of types where this field does not exist. This is a general
>   issue with Lucene indices: they don’t like sparsity. Sparse postings
>   lists can’t be compressed efficiently because of high deltas between
>   consecutive matches. And the issue is even worse with doc values: for
>   speed reasons, doc values often reserve a fixed amount of disk space
>   for every document, so that values can be addressed efficiently. This
>   means that if Lucene establishes that it needs one byte to store all
>   value of a given numeric field, it will also consume one byte for
>   documents that don’t have a value for this field.

Ref: [Index-vs-Types](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparsity is not strictly related to many types. In the context of the blog post (types vs. indices) using multiple types instead of multiple indices does indeed come with the downside of having sparse fields: if one defines 3 types in an index where each type has one field: `field1` in type `type1`, `field2` in type `type2` and `field3` in type `type3`, every document added to this index, no matter to which type it belongs, it **will have all those three fields in it (at Lucene level)**. But for every type only the field belonging to that type will have value. Which means that each document of the index will be 1/3 populated.

This is, also, why Elasticsearch requires the fields with the same name, but in different types, to have the same field type: because at Lucene level, this is all one field for all documents in that index, no matter the type.

The same happens with one type in one index and documents having 3 fields. If those fields barely have values (like in your case), still sparsity happens.